# Generate Two Seperate XML Files by Walking DOM Tree and Using Attributes

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I need to segregate xml code into two separate files by using the optional attribute values. I prefer to use the XML::LibXML DOM methods, using Perl.

```
Sample XML code excerpt:
...
<LocalJMS>
  <Name>ZLAT</Name>
  <PrimaryConnection>
    <Address string="ops">ops.zla</Address>
    <Address string="spt">spt.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </PrimaryConnection>
  <SecondaryConnection string="ops">
    <Address>abc.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </SecondaryConnection>
</LocalJMS>
```

The desirable resulting two final xml files would be:

```
1.) OPS file:
...
 <LocalJMS>
   <Name>ZLAT</Name>
   <PrimaryConnection>
     <Address>ops.zla</Address>
     <Port>77777</Port>
   </PrimaryConnection>
   <SecondaryConnection>
     <Address>abc.zla</Address>
     <Port>77777</Port>
   </SecondaryConnection>
 </LocalJMS>

2.) SPT file:
...
 <LocalJMS>
   <Name>ZLAT</Name>
   <PrimaryConnection>
     <Address>spt.zla</Address>
     <Port>77777</Port>
   </PrimaryConnection>
 </LocalJMS>
```

I have no problem/issue removing the attributes prior to generating the two final xml files, nor do I have any issue with making a decision on a element with an attribute that has no child elements - I can handle that as far pumping the xml content to the correct final xml file when I walk the DOM tree and checking on the childnodes.

But the problem I'm encountering is when the attribute is defined within a child element (e.g. 'SecondaryConnection', which is a child of 'LocalJMS').
If I "walk" the DOM tree, I will first encounter the parent element 'LocalJMS', and I need some of it's children elements (e.g. 'Name', 'PrimaryConnection') to go to both final files, but then I only need the 'SecondaryConnection' element to go only to the OPS xml file (not the SPT file). [btw, the attribute is applicable to all child nodes, i.e. 'Address' & 'Port']

I'm looking for some ideas - maybe using parse_balanced_chunk or work from the deepest part of the originally xml file and work outwards, cycling thru each child node.  I hate like heck to have to use traditional grep patterns etc and treat the xml file like a simple text file - I was hoping to take advantage of the DOM methods.

Comment: So what is the problem with yet another attribute? If you're OK with `Name` and `PrimaryConn..` what is wrong with `SecondaryConn..`?  (And, by what criteria do you decide which goes where?)

Comment: zdim -
thank you for your attention... the criteria is the attribute values.  When I walk the DOM, the top parent node contains a child node with an attribute - an attribute that is needed as criteria, but since the parent node is processed first (which contains a child node with an attribute), I end up processing the parent node without processing the child node yet.  I won't be able to process the child node with attribute until I've already processed the parent node, which then will be too late.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you parse the original XML, and then for each value of the `string` attribute you can clone the whole document and remove all elements that have an attribute with any value for `string` different from the one required

It would look like this. I am sure you're able to alter the output to something more appropriate if necessary

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => 'sample.xml' );

for my $string ( qw/ ops spt / ) {

    print "\$string = $string\n\n";

    my $copy = $dom->cloneNode(1);

    for my $unwanted ( $copy->findnodes("//*[\@string != '$string']") ) {
        my $parent = $unwanted->parentNode;
        $parent->removeChild($unwanted);
    }

    print $copy, "\n\n---\n\n";
}
```

#### output

```
$string = ops

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LocalJMS>
  <Name>ZLAT</Name>
  <PrimaryConnection>
    <Address string="ops">ops.zla</Address>

    <Port>77777</Port>
  </PrimaryConnection>
  <SecondaryConnection string="ops">
    <Address>abc.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </SecondaryConnection>
</LocalJMS>


---

$string = spt

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LocalJMS>
  <Name>ZLAT</Name>
  <PrimaryConnection>

    <Address string="spt">spt.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </PrimaryConnection>

</LocalJMS>


---

[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not XML parsing like you wanted, but seems to work for your sample data. Tags with a `string="filename"` attribute goes only into only that file (where filename is uppercased), with the `string` attribute removed. And all other tags goes into all files:

```
my $input=join"",<DATA>;
my @string=$input=~/ string="(\w+)"/g;
for my $s (@string){
    my $output=$input;
    $output=~
      s{ (\s*) <(\w+)\s* ([^>]*?) string="(\w+)" (.*?</\2>) }
       { $4 eq $s ? "$1<$2$3$5" : ""                        }gsex;
    open my $FH, '>', uc($s) or die;
    print $FH $output;
    close($FH)
}
__DATA__
<LocalJMS>
  <Name>ZLAT</Name>
  <PrimaryConnection>
    <Address string="ops">ops.zla</Address>
    <Address string="spt">spt.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </PrimaryConnection>
  <SecondaryConnection string="ops">
    <Address>abc.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </SecondaryConnection>
</LocalJMS>
```

Output:

```
$ cat OPS 
<LocalJMS>
  <Name>ZLAT</Name>
  <PrimaryConnection>
    <Address>ops.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </PrimaryConnection>
  <SecondaryConnection>
    <Address>abc.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </SecondaryConnection>
</LocalJMS>

$ cat SPT
<LocalJMS>
  <Name>ZLAT</Name>
  <PrimaryConnection>
    <Address>spt.zla</Address>
    <Port>77777</Port>
  </PrimaryConnection>
</LocalJMS>
```

Comment: Kjetil S. -  
I thank you for the response ... although I understand exactly what you are suggesting, I'm a little hung-up on your line:
     s{ (\s*) <(\w+)\s* ([^>]*?) string="(\w+)" (.*?</\2>) } 
       { $4 eq $s ? "$1<$2$3$5" : ""                        }grsex;   I can't seem to use the "r" modifier (i.e., can only use "gsex").  But with that said, when I attempt to debug this stmt by printing the 1st capture group $1, I'm getting empty value.

Comment: @CraigP Aha, the `/r` modifier needs Perl version >= 5.14 (from 2011). I have rewritten my answer to not use `/r` now. The `$1` can be empty or it can contain `\s` chars, that is spaces, tabs, newlines and such.

Comment: The /r non-destructive option is not available until  v5.14, I'm running v5.10.1

Comment: I never used the "e" 'evaluate the right-hand side as an expression' modifier  - pretty cool ... you given me something I hopefully can work off of ...ty!